# Finding standard matrix linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

$T: R^2 \rightarrow R^2$

First rotate point through $\frac{-3\pi}{4}$ clockwise and the reflect points through the horizontal x axis.

I know what $T(e_1)$ and $T(e_2)$ is

Let $a= \begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
$

But I am not sure how reflect by the x axis.

Comment: So, have you got the coordinates of the final $T(e_1)$ and $T(e_2)$?

Comment: To reflect in the x-axis, change the signs of the y-coordinates.

Comment: let me see actually I think I made a mistake let me re edit.

Comment: sin(-135) is $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two ways to finish:

1. The matrix $a$ you wrote up is the matrix of rotation by $+135^\circ$ (that is, by $-135^\circ$ clockwise). 
   Now write up also the matrix $b$ of reflection: that leaves $e_1$ and maps $e_2$ to $-e_2$. 
   Finally, the matrix of $T$ will be $ba$.
2. You follow the instruction of $T$ for the basis vectors $e_1=\pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $e_2=\pmatrix{0\\1}$, then write the coordinates of $T(e_1)$ in the first column and those of $T(e_2)$ in the second column.

E.g., for the reflection, using advice 2., we will get $b=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$, and you can verify that for any point $p=\pmatrix{x\\y}$ in the plane, the matrix product $bp$ will be indeed the reflection of $p$.